# Connect Access Database to Qlik Sense Enterprise

Tags: ms-access, odbc, oledb, qliksense

I have an Access 2010 Database (.accdb) and I am attempting to connect it to Qlik Sense Enterprise.

With QS Enterprise, I was able to connect an Access Database (.mdb) using OLE DB connectivity, but I have not had any luck connecting a .accdb database using this method.

I was able to connect a .accdb database file using QS Desktop with an ODBC Connection, but OLE DB has been a nuisance.  I updated my Access 2010 Redistributable Driver (though it did not need it) and that did not fix the problem.

I tried saving my .accdb file as a .mdb, but I was given an error saying:

"You cannot save this database in an earlier version format, because it uses features that require the current file format. 
These features include attachments, multi-valued fields, offline data, data macros, calculated Columns, links to unsupported external files, newer sort orders, newer encryption types, and navigation controls."

I am not entirely sure why I can connect the .accdb file through QS Desktop, but not through QS Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OLEDB check you have the Jet 4.0 data driver installed on the server.